# How do you modify an npm library you are using in your project?

Tags: npm, open-source, updates, npm-install, package.json

I'm using [**ng-bootstrap**](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) in my Angular project.

The problem is that **ng-bootstrap** is still in its early stages and missing lots of functionality. I have added a simple feature within the code in my `node_modules/@ng-bootstrap` directory.

The trouble is that I worry that if/when there is an update to `ng-bootstrap` and I update my project with it, my local changes in the functionality will be overwritten and lost.

What are some techniques to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You've effectively just created your own "branch" of that package. You could submit a pull request if the functionality is something that should be there for everyone. Since you have custom changes, you're responsible for making sure updates don't overwrite them.

If i needed to so something like this, i'd see if there was a way to implement the changes without modifying the ng-bootstrap files themselves. Without knowing what the change is, i can't say how that might be accomplished. One option there is to not use a package manager for that framework, or let the package manager get the "official" files, and then copy them somewhere else that you actually use. You're still responsible for making sure to merge changes in when the framework updates, but at least it won't be automatically overwritten.

Comment: Is there some way to make a pull request from within the directory I modified? It would seem I need to clone the actual GitHub repo and remake the change there, which would be inconvenient

Comment: You could try cloning the repo (from https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap ?) into a new directory, and then copying your modified files on top to get the changes. Or you could generate a diff and make those changes in a newly cloned work area.

Edit: If you are copying files on top to get changes, be very careful to inspect the changes as you don't want to clobber something else.